# Applying multiple functions (Mean., STD etc ) across columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data of 4 columns and 8 rows...

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3,7], [2, 8, 6,8],[3, 2, 3,7], [4, 4, 6,8],[5, 2, 3,7], [6, 1, 6,8],[7, 8, 3,7], [8, 9, 6,8]], columns=['time','A', 'B', 'C'])

       time  A  B  C
    0     1  2  3  7
    1     2  8  6  8
    2     3  2  3  7
    3     4  4  6  8
    4     5  2  3  7
    5     6  1  6  8  
    6     7  8  3  7
    7     8  9  6  8
```

I want to take mean and STD of column A and C, across columns not rows. e.g Mean and STD of 2 and 7 is "" (mean) and "3.535533906" (STD) respectively as following.

I want my result to look like this...

```
      Mean  STD
    0 4.7   3.535533906
    1 8     0
    2 .     .
    3 .     .
    . .     .
    . .     .
```

However, when I try to do

`df= df.loc[(df.time>=2) & (df.time<=7),['A','C']],(['mean','std'])`

I get the following error...

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'time'

I've tried to find solutions by doing this as well but in vain :

```
df= df.loc[(df.time>=2) & (df.time<=7),['A','C']].agg(['mean','std'])
```

but it gives me result of all rows mean and STD.

```
                 A         C
    mean  4.166667  7.500000
    std   3.125167  0.547723
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way:

```
In [346]: df[['A','C']].T.agg(['mean','std']).T
Out[346]:
   mean       std
0   4.5  3.535534
1   8.0  0.000000
2   4.5  3.535534
3   6.0  2.828427
4   4.5  3.535534
5   4.5  4.949747
6   7.5  0.707107
7   8.5  0.707107
```

or as a new columns in the original DF:

```
In [347]: df[['Mean','STD']] = df[['A','C']].T.agg(['mean','std']).T

In [348]: df
Out[348]:
   time  A  B  C  Mean       STD
0     1  2  3  7   4.5  3.535534
1     2  8  6  8   8.0  0.000000
2     3  2  3  7   4.5  3.535534
3     4  4  6  8   6.0  2.828427
4     5  2  3  7   4.5  3.535534
5     6  1  6  8   4.5  4.949747
6     7  8  3  7   7.5  0.707107
7     8  9  6  8   8.5  0.707107
```

Comment: borrowed your T :-)

Comment: @Wen, it's not mine - it belongs to Pandas and Numpy! :-D

Comment: Also you are ohk to add this one `df['mean'],df['std'] = df[['A','C']].mean(1),df[['A','C']].std(1)`

Comment: @Dark, why don't you want to add it as an answer? :)

Comment: @MaxU, Great, But am looking for a range of rows like starting from time=2 to time =7.

Comment: @M.irfan, please post your desired data set in your question based on your sample data set

Comment: @M.irfan can't you just work on that i.e `df.loc[(df.time.between(2,7)),['A','C']].T.agg(`

Comment: @ MaxU. Am sorry i didnt get u. My desired data is there "my result". Or do you mean something different ?

Comment: @M.irfan, all answers posted here provide you your desired result set (starting from index `0`) ;)

Comment: @Dark, Could you please complete your last comment ?

Comment: `df[['Mean','STD']] = df.loc[(df.time.between(2,7)),['A','C']].T.agg(['mean','std']).T`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `describe`

```
df[['A','C']].T.describe().T[['mean','std']]
Out[865]: 
   mean       std
0   4.5  3.535534
1   8.0  0.000000
2   4.5  3.535534
3   6.0  2.828427
4   4.5  3.535534
5   4.5  4.949747
6   7.5  0.707107
7   8.5  0.707107
```

Comment: Great. But am looking for a range of rows like starting from time=2 to time =7.

Comment: @M.irfan you already done by yourself I think `df.loc[(df.time>=2) & (df.time<=7),['A','C']].T.describe().T[['mean','std']]`

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much.